# HTTP requests in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, http

I am currently working on a school project using android. I have java code that sends an HTTP request to a server. It works just find on my laptop using eclipse, but when I try it on my android tablet (an android trio using android 4.4), it does not work. Instead it returns an error (An error occurred while sending the request: in the catch). It is going by the try block and moving to the catch block.

I am attaching the code used for the HTTP request below. I will be leaving out the server information for security reasons. I know the code works, like I said It works on my desktop. Why won't it work with my tablet? Can someone give me a hand with this?

```
package com.example.tito.profile1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GetUserTest
{

String userName;

public GetUserTest()
{
    userName = "Before try";
    GetUserRequest request = new GetUserRequest();
    request.setSecurityString("Left out for security");
    request.setUserId(1);
    request.setUserIdToGet(1);

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String data = gson.toJson(request);


    try
    {
        URL urlObject = new URL("http://Left out for security");


        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
        //userName = connection.toString();

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(120000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(120000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());


        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();



        if(connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"utf-8"));

            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                builder.append(inputLine);
            }

            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.close();
            }

            String result = builder.toString();

            GetUserResponse response = gson.fromJson(result, GetUserResponse.class);

            System.out.println(response.getMessage());


            if (response.getSuccess() == true)
            {
                UserInfo user = response.getUser();

                /*System.out.println("UserName: " + user.getUserName());
                System.out.println("DisplayName: " + user.getDisplayName());
                System.out.println("Description: " + user.getDescription());
                System.out.println("Email: " + user.getEmail());
                System.out.println("ProductCount: " + user.getProductCount());
                System.out.println("FollowedUsers: " + user.getFollowedUsers());
                System.out.println("FollowingUsers: " + user.getFollowingUsers());*/
                //System.out.println("Join Date:" + user.getCreatedDate());

               // userName = "in if statement";

               // userName = user.getDisplayName();
            }
        }
        else
        {
           userName = "error in after else";
           //userName = "An error occurred while sending the request: " + connection.getResponseMessage();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        userName = "An error occurred while sending the request: in the catch ";

    }
}

public String sendBack()
{
    return userName;
}
```

}

Comment: What error are you getting in logcat? post log

Comment: It's not making contact with the server. When I debug the code, it looks like its not creating the OutputStreamWriter object. Instead of going into the try block, it goes straight to the catch.

Comment: Which catch? Which exception in the logcat? Why should this be asked twice? Give info! Look in the logcat.

Comment: `userName = "An error occurred while sending the request: in the catch ";`. An error? Which error? You should inform the user of your app and yourself better. Use ex.getMessage() as it contains the exception info. username = ex.getMessage();

Comment: From where do you call new GetUserTest()?

Comment: `userName = "error in after else";` Also bad message. You should tell which response code you expected and which one you got instead!